# Convert XML to XML using XSL (XSLT) & API

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the input xml as below

```
<node>
    <id>1234</id>
    <value1>DoNoChange</value1>
    <value2></value2>
    <value3></value3>
</node>
```

Now, i would use the XSL to convert the above XML to below one

```
<node>
    <id>1234</id>
    <value1>DoNoChange</value1>
    <value2>NewValue2</value2>
    <value2>NewValue3</value2>
</node>
```

Which NewValue2 and NewValue3 is the response content from an API calls such as `http://example.com/api/getDataByID/1234` which will return response as

```
<data>
   <value2>NewValue2</value2>
   <value3>NewValue3</value3>
<data>
```

Could you please advice my how can build the XSL for it?

**What I have tried so far is**

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:param name="code" select="1234"/>

 <xsl:variable name="endpoint" as="xs:string" select="'http://example.com/api/getDataByID/1'"/>
      <!-- the http request element -->
      <xsl:variable name="request">
         <http-request method="get" mime-type="application/xml" content-type="application/xml">

         </http-request>
      </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node/id">    
  <xsl:variable name="rest_response" select="ex:httpSend($request, $endpoint)"/>
  <id><xsl:value-of select="$rest_response/data"/></id>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The logic I'm trying to do are**

- When I see the match of node/id
- I will call API using "id" as a param to a Rest API (Get Method)
  (Note: currently I don't know how to use id as param, I hardcoded so
  far)
- Capture the response of the API into a variable Populate variable
  data to fields such as "value2", value3"  (Note: This one I have no
  clue how to make it)

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. Actually in this case, I have tried myself many ways in couple days already but so far it doesn't go well. I just don't want to confused here with many "not working" ways.

Comment: "So far it doesn't go well" is not something we can work with.  Post specific code and ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide an answer. We don't know what the response from the API looks like. Is it XML or something else?

Comment: P.S. If you're using XSLT 2.0, then tagging your question `exslt` makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

If your call to the API returns an XML response, then you should be able to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="id | value1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="response" select="document(concat('http://example.com/api/getDataByID/', id))" />
        <value2>
            <xsl:value-of select="$response/data/value2"/>
        </value2>
        <value3>
            <xsl:value-of select="$response/data/value3"/>
        </value3>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Untested, because no testing environment has been provided.

Comment: Thanks Michael a lot. Could we have better way which we don't have to put <value2>
            <xsl:value-of select="$response/data/value2"/>
        </value2>
        <value3>
            <xsl:value-of select="$response/data/value3"/>
        </value3>
The reason is my XML has many fields needs to be populated from the API. The example just 2 fields but actually in real use cases will be around 100 fields

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "better way". You could copy the elements instead of extracting their values. This is just an example; once you have the response in the variable, you can parse it any way you like.

Comment: Oh, currently your suggestion is we need to put <value2></value2> , <value3></value3> ... and so on under <xsl:template match="/node"> .... I'm asking do we have any way just loop on all nodes and map all of them

Comment: My suggestion is based on the premise that the matching names are just a coincidence. If not, then you can ignore the input and just copy the nodes from the response. If you need something more elaborate than that, post a new question.